# Getting a hash of all values inside form in Ember

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, ember.js

I am submitting a form to create a new `Review` in Ember.js. The form is linked to an action on my `reviews/new` controller.

Here is my form:
*templates/reviews/new.hbs*

```
  <form {{action "createReview" on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=name}}
    {{input value=content}}

    <input type="submit" value="Post this review" class="button">
  </form>
```

And my controller:
*controllers/reviews/new/js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    createReview: function(params) {
      console.log(this.get('name'));
      console.log(this.get('content');
    }
  }
});
```

At the moment my trouble is accessing the form field values in an efficent way. Note that `this.get('name')` does print out the value of the `name` input field and the same for `this.get('content')`.

But is there a nice way to get all the form field values in a hash? Something like: `this.get('allAttributes')` which would output:

```
{name: "John Doe", content: "Bla bla-bla bla blaaaaah"}
```

**EDIT**

`content` is a ***reserved word in ember. Do not name an attribute "content"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an object on your controller that you use for the forms:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  formFields: Ember.Object.create(),
  actions: {
    createReview: function(params) {
      console.log(this.get('formFields.name'));
      console.log(this.get('formFields.content');
    }
  }
});
```

You need to use an Ember object so that the bindings will work.

```
  <form {{action "createReview" on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=formFields.name}}
    {{input value=formFields.content}}

    <input type="submit" value="Post this review" class="button">
  </form>
```

Comment: Follow-up question.  Let's say the OP had an action that made an Ajax call like : 
`Ember.$.ajax('/foo').done(function(res){ ... });` .  What's the correct way in the done handler for someone to update `formFields` so that it properly updates the View ?

Answer (score 0):

Review model is essential object for this.

```
// reviews/new route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('review', {
      //predefined properties here
    }); 
  },
  actions: {
    // bubbling thru controller
    createReview: function() {
       this.get('model').save().then(function(review) {
          // action you needs if any
          self.transitionTo('reviews');
       }, function() {
          // on errors
       });
    },
    cancel: function() {
        this.transitionTo('reviews');
    }
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    var model = this.modelFor( this.routeName );
    if (model.get('isNew')) {
        model.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});


//template
<form {{action "createReview" on="submit"}}>
  {{input value=model.name}}

  //errors example it depends of your backend and adapter
  {{#each model.errors.name as |error|}}
      <div class="error">
        {{error.message}}
      </div>
  {{/each}

  {{input value=model.content}}

  <input type="submit" value="Post this review" class="button">
  <button {{action "cancel"}}>Cancel</button>
</form>
```